# How to get HDMI-CEC internal adapter on NUC to work?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, kodi, hdmi-cec

I have an internal Pulse Eight CEC-HDMI adapter connected to my NUC NUC7PJYH. I have Kodi version 18.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS on the NUC. I have an HDMI cable connected from my NUC on HDMI port 1, to port 1 on my Philips TV. In Kodi the CEC-HDMI adapter has been recognised. However, I cannot use my TV's remote to control Kodi.

When I quit Kodi I get the following output from the command (I have to quit Kodi for the command to work):

```
$ echo 'scan' | cec-client -s -d 1

opening a connection to the CEC adapter...
requesting CEC bus information ...
CEC bus information
===================
device #1: Recorder 1
address:       1.0.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        Pulse Eight
osd string:    CECTester
CEC version:   1.4
power status:  on
language:      eng

currently active source: unknown (-1)
```

Seems my NUC cannot see my TV. I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.1 without Kodi installed. I took the HDMI cable from my NUC, put it in the Raspberry Pi, then ran the same command:

```
$ echo 'scan' | cec-client -s -d 1

opening a connection to the CEC adapter...
requesting CEC bus information ...
CEC bus information
===================
device #0: TV
address:       0.0.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        Unknown
osd string:    TV
CEC version:   1.4
power status:  standby
language:      ???


device #1: Recorder 1
address:       1.0.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        Pulse Eight
osd string:    CECTester
CEC version:   1.4
power status:  on
language:      eng


currently active source: unknown (-1)
```

So from Raspberry Pi my TV is recognised. I can run this command to turn the TV on from standby.

```
$  echo 'on 0' | cec-client -s -d 1
```

The HDMI cable is not the problem. How to get the CEC-HDMI adapter working on my NUC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the HDMI cable in my NUC from HDMI port 1 to port 2 and now I can control Kodi with my TV remote.